# XPS 13 (2015) Incredibly slow on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: firefox, dell, matlab

My Dell XPS 2015 used to work fine but lately (half year more or less),
it has been intolerably slow.
I usually run multiple firefox tab,spotify, and sometimes a Jetbrains IDE or Matlab.
If I try to run all these combined (2 open tabs on my browser), everything
becomes insanely slow and everything halts now and then.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is the available space for the system.
Accumulated dust can make cooling lose effectiveness resulting in slower CPU performance. It is recommended to take apart notebooks and clean them every few years.